# Executing a conditional method only one time for a callback with multiple methods. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

In a Rails app, I'm using an after_update call back that runs multiple methods upon passing a conditional method such as below:

*app/models/my_model.rb*

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :method_1, :method_2, :method_3, if: :this_happens?
  #some custom methods
private
  def this_happens?
    # a condition that returns true or false here
  end
end
```

I've noticed that the method `this_happens?` is executed three times, just before `:method_1`, `:method_2`, `:method_3`.

This make sense as any of those three call back methods could change the data in such a way that the condition has to be evaluated again to make sure it's met in every case. However, when you know those 3 methods are not changing the data in any way that could alter the condition evaluation, is it possible to run `this_happens?` only once and gain some efficiency?

I don't seem to find anything online and wonder if anyone could advise.

PS. using Rails 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulation is the one of the easiest way that you can choose to overcome this situation.

Just wrap your methods in another one, then it will only check `this_happens?` one time.

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :combine_methods, if: :this_happens?
  #some custom methods
private
  def combine_methods
    method_1
    method_2
    method_3
  end

  def this_happens?
    # a condition that returns true or false here
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks mdegis. Of course! I was somehow looking for a built-in solution but your way make sense. How didn't I think about that!